# Disabling search in a WPF FlowDocument

Tags: wpf, flowdocument

I have a FlowDocument that is defined in XAML like this;

```
<FlowDocumentScrollViewer>
    <FlowDocument>
        <Paragraph>
            <Run>Hello</Run>
        </Paragraph>
    </FlowDocument>
</FlowDocumentScrollViewer>
```

What I'd like to do is prevent the Find and Zoom controls from appearing when you press Ctrl-F or F3.

Is this possible?

Thanks in advance!
Matt

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could handle the `PreviewKeyDown` event for this control, and if either Ctrl-F or F3 is pressed, mark the event as handled. This should prevent the control itself from responding to that event and displaying the Find and Zoom controls.